# Why loadNibNamed:owner:options will automatically install on current view?

Tags: ios

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];    
    UIView *testView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"VBImageView" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];

    NSLog(@"%d", [self.view.subviews count]); // result is 1
}
```

Something I don't understand is, just by calling `loadNibNamed` method will actually load  imageView and add to current subview? Why? Can someone please explain that?

---

#### Updates

I found that in xib file, the `Files's owner` has the view delegate setup, If I remove this delegate, then the view will not automatically setup. what doest that view delegate mean?

#### I have now uploaded all the source files at [here](https://mega.co.nz/#!fUdBURQZ!OjOXHAV_guMSXX1BWOcl3EGYcZ5p2kaIQFtxAnYUZgs)

Comment: the result of `[self.view.subviews count]` does not prove `loadNibNamed` did load imageView and add to current view. are there any other view in your viewController's view in xib file?

Comment: This is an empty xcode5 project, I just created a vc with nib file enabled, everything else is empty.

Comment: So `VBImageView` XIB has a link to the `view` property of the view controller (owner)?

Comment: @johnMa I found that may hard to explain, so I uploaded the project source files, please check above updates. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing but log **0** , so I think your view controller's view is not empty, could you try `NSLog(@"%@", self.view.subviews)` and show me the result?

for the second question, that view outlet just the property of your ViewController,that view will not automatically setup when disconnect because your window could not find that view to add.

**EDIT:**

That's too wired man, I download your source code and run it on simulator, it log **0** too.[image]

after I delete `loadFromNib` method in `viewDidLoad`,it log **2**.then I found there are two guide layout and one view in your storyboard.[image]

By delete that view in storyboard, it log zero. so I think this is the reason .However, I not familiar with storyboard , so I can't completely explain it.sorry about that.

Comment: If I don't add any code in viewdidload, then subview count will be 2, they are 2 UILayoutGuide objects.